# How to fix compatibility issues in newer versions of excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro to hide and minimize the application on startup and show only the user form.And if i copy and change the necessary paths in another pc it works just fine if that pc has excel 2007 version.However if a PC has a higher version like 2013 the application doesnt hide instead it opens a window in the background.Is the a way to fix this? Am i not enabling or disable a particular setting in the newer versions?

image named "7.jpg" [image]shows how it looks if run on a pc with excel 2007 and the second image [image] is a representation of how it looks in excel 2013 or any other higher version.Also I have problems running the code in higher version sometimes. Please help!

Code used (on opening a workbook)

```
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
Application.Visible = False


'clearing ranges
Sheets("PO").Range("C22:C33").ClearContents
Sheets("PO").Range("J22:J33").ClearContents

UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: In Excel 2010 it also works as you described for the 2007 Version. I'll try to test this once I'm home from work and can run it on Office 365. (if it isn't answered by then)

Comment: And here, with Office 365, Excel also opens with just the user form showing using your code in a Workbooks_Open procedure.

Comment: @rohrl77 Type the code in excel 2007 and then copy that sheet and run the macro it in a computer with excel 2013/16 etc. That’s when i’m having issues. And Thanks with your 2010 version effort.Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Wait... you said to copy the "sheet"? The code you are showing needs to be in the Workbook Module, hence the `Workbook_Open()`. Are you copying it manually to the new workbook?

Comment: @rohrl77 copy the “Workbook”  i must have typed ”Worksheet” by mistake sorry. Basically , i have created a data entry thingy with user forms and all in my pc and now i want  others to use it too. So i copied my “.xlsm Workbook” and pasted it in another person’s pc updated all the necessary links and everything. However , he happened to have excel 2013 and due to that i have the above problem (is what i think).Because , i copied and pasted it in another pc with windows 2007. I worked just fine on that pc. So i’m guessing it might be because of the newer versions?

Comment: Just to rule this one out, try: `Application.WindowState = xlMinimized` instead. I'm also curious if going through code in debug mode (F8) will work. Sometimes `Application.WindowState = xlMinimized _ Application.WindowState = xlNormal _ ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized` does work in run time.

Comment: Ok. Will check at home if I can reproduce the behaviour